# Making anonymous block in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need to build an anonymous block to insert values in a table of configuration with this columns: config and value.

This is what I need to insert:

```
Config: ‘country’       Value: ‘Argentina’
Config: ‘moneysign’     Value: ‘$’
Config: ‘dateformat’    Value: ‘DD/MM/YYYY’
```

I have to validate that the 3 insertions are correct. In case of failure, identify which failed and return the DB to the consistent state it was before starting the script.

Comment: OK, what's your question?  (Sounds like you are just repeating a homework assignment and asking someone to write it for you.)

Comment: What is an anonymous script? How will you call it?

Comment: You were probably thinking about PL/SQL block, but maybe simple procedure with exception handling would work here? Anyway that is NOT a question, you didn't even try to write something yourself - like guys above say it's not a homework site.

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO CONFIG_TABLE (CONFIG, VAL) VALUES ('country', 'Argentia');
  INSERT INTO CONFIG_TABLE (CONFIG, VAL) VALUES ('moneysign', '$');
  INSERT INTO CONFIG_TABLE (CONFIG, VAL) VALUES ('dateformat', 'DD/MM/YYYY');
  COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLCODE||' -ERROR- '||SQLERRM);
    ROLLBACK;
END;
```

Comment: What is that exception handler doing, apart from obscuring the error stack, duplicating `sqlcode` and hiding failures?

Comment: I just want to demonstrate how the exception handling of PL/SQL works.

Comment: I'm not sure the example does that.